# How to get name of student in a particular field in odoo?

Tags: field, odoo, odoo-12

I have a student form, in which, when a student select his/her date of birth, his age will show in "Calculated Age" field.

Now, I want that instead of showing only digit in numbers, I want to show it as:

Hi, Srishti! Your age is 9.

Note that "Srishti" is a name given in name field.

Please help.

Regards

Adesh Paul

```
class StudentStudent(models.Model):
    _name = 'student.student'

    student_dob = fields.Date(string="Date of Birth")
    age = fields.Integer(string='Age')
    calc_age = fields.Char(string="Calculated Age", readonly=True)

    @api.onchange('student_dob')
    def _onchange_birth_date(self):
        """Updates age field when birth_date is changed"""
        if self.student_dob:
            d1 = datetime.strptime(str(self.student_dob), "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            d2 = date.today()
            self.calc_age = relativedelta(d2, d1).years
```

Comment: what you have tried so far? Share your code

Comment: @api.onchange('student_dob')
    def _onchange_birth_date(self):
        if self.student_dob:
            d1 = datetime.strptime(str(self.student_dob), "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            d2 = date.today()
            self.calc_age = relativedelta(d2, d1).years

Fields are:

    student_dob = fields.Date(string="Date of Birth")
    calc_age = fields.Char(string="Calculated Age", readonly=True)

Answer (score 1):

You can define `age` and `calc_age` as computed fields instead of using `onchange` method to set their values.

You can use the same compute method since both fields depend on the same field `student_dob`.

***Example:***

```
student_dob = fields.Date(string="Date of Birth")
age = fields.Integer(string='Age', compute="_compute_age")
calc_age = fields.Char(string="Calculated Age", compute="_compute_age")
    
@api.depends('student_dob')
def _compute_age(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.student_dob:
            age = relativedelta(
                fields.Date.today(),
                record.student_dob,
            ).years
            record.age = age
            record.calc_age = 'Hi, {}! Your age is {}'.format(record.name, age)
```

Import `relativedelta` from `dateutil.relativedelta`.